# How do I convert a result from 1000 to 1000.00 in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

My select query is:

```
Select ROUND(1000,2) from dual;
```

and the result of the query returns as follows :

> ROUND(1000,2) ---> 1000

I want to return like this :1000.00

How do I convert it?

Comment: `cast(1000 as decimal(12,2))`

Comment: The result is correct. 1000 = 1000.00 = 1000.0000000. If you want to display it differently, you *could* use Oracle's `TO_CHAR`, but it would be way better to have your GUI or Website care about the display (for it will know whether its user wants a comma or a decimal point for the decimal separator, which your DBMS may not know).

Comment: Try this: TO_CHAR(ROUND(1000, 2), '99999D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using <kbd>[Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)</kbd> :

```
Select to_char(<numeric_column>,'fm999990D00','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') as "Number"
  From <your table>
```

where **D** stands for **decimal character** in this case( *If needed, then might be converted to `'fm999G990D00'` for the money format containing comma seperator by using **G** character in this case such as 12345 -> 12,345.00*  )

Comment: `D` stands for decimal character rather than "dot" as some countries use dots for thousands separator and commas for the decimal separator and vice versa for others.

Comment: exactly, we even use the format for currency as `'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'''` in Turkey. Fixed, thanks @MT0

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1000, 'FM9999999.90')
FROM dual;
```

Regarding using a character type here, your main interest seems to be to view your numeric data a certain way.